# Select beetween dates and limited ip

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a simple login system with between dates and limited IP, but MySQL query gives me some error.

I want to control if users logged in more then limited IP and between limited dates

This is a mysql query:

```
SELECT *, count(l.ip) as total FROM login_card as c
INNER JOIN cart_log  as l
WHERE c.login_name = "toruser" AND c.login_pass = "54trvd"
AND l.dt > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL c.end_dt MONTH)
AND total > c.total_ip
```

[image]

Comment: what error you got..?

Comment: Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'  this is error and not counting ip

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function in the `WHERE` clause. Try use `HAVING` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT User.*
FROM
login_card User
INNER JOIN
(SELECT userid,COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) as Total_ips
   FROM
   cart_log
   INNER JOIN login_card ON login_card.`userid`=cart_log.`userid` AND cart_log.dt > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL login_card.end_dt MONTH)
   group by userid) T ON User.`userid` = T.`userid` AND T.`Total_ips` > User.`total_ip`
WHERE User.login_name = 'toruser' AND User.login_pass = '54trvd'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the error getting.. I have edited now please check

Comment: If you remove where clause you will get those users , who loged in more than the limited ip..

Comment: you are right but i want to control dates also. since first login until 3 month some thing like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
SELECT *, count(l.ip) as total FROM login_card as c
INNER JOIN cart_log  as l
WHERE c.login_name = "toruser" AND c.login_pass = "54trvd"
AND l.dt > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL c.end_dt MONTH)
AND count(l.ip) > c.total_ip
```

Let me know what you get...

Comment: error log: Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'